# html strange behavior of html css directory

Tags: html, css

I run my html on localhost 
this is what i got when i put my css file on css folder

```
  href="css/well.css"
```

[well.css in css folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOdra.png)
[image]

and this is what i got when i put well.css on the same directory as index.php

```
href="well.css"
```

[well.css on the same directory as index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfnsk.png)

[image]

this is well.css and im using bootstrap for this site

```
#well{
color:white;
}
#topping{
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
.active{
  background-color: white;
}
#rite{
  background-image:url("../1.jpg");
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-repeat: fixed;
}
#submit{
  width:100px;
  margin-left:90%;
  background-color:white;
}
#sing{
  background-color: white;
  color:#323280;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading{
  background-color: #bd1919;
  color:white;
}
.panel-default > .panel-footer {
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
```

my question is directory of the css file can change the appearance of the site?
why the panel heading has a different color even though it has the same css?

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: Paste it below bootstrap link.

Comment: @Dražen trying it now

Comment: @Dražen done but still the same

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, can directory of the css file can change the
>   appearance of the site?

Yes it can.

For example, when you use a relative path, as in `background-image:url("../1.jpg");`, the browser will look for the image in a folder one level above then folder of the CSS file.

So if your folder structure looks like this

```
root/www/css/well.css
root/www/1.jpg
```

and you move the CSS like this

```
root/www/well.css
root/www/1.jpg
```

the browser will not find the image as it is no longer one level above the CSS folder

Comment: Yeah i got it, hut i dont actually use rite id in index.php and i use the same css , but it shows different color of panel heading just like on the picture i uploaded